# wkWebView close window - autoclose

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

When I click a pop up in wkWebView, I get that action via

```
- (nullable WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures{
if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {

    //[webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    [self showInternalWeb:navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

and displaying the link in a different controller.

I would like to dismiss that controller automatically when the window is closed. In my laptop browser, the controller is automatically closed after I press a button on the new window. I am wondering how code this functionality myself.

I have tried calling:

```
[userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"window.close()"];
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"window.close()" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable obj, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"suces");
}];
```

This calls webViewDidClose normally, but not when the window becomes blank.

Answer (score -2):

Please check that, did you set your UIDelegate for the webView..

```
webView.UIDelegate = self;
```